# Can I justify using a one-tailed test in for this interaction effect?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, statistical-power, post-hoc, apriori

I have an experimental setup with 2 factors, site and disturbance treatment.  I have reason to suspect that plots at site A will be more affected by treatment than plots at site B.  My response variable is change in the % of the plot covered by a species over time.  Site A has about half the starting species cover as site B.  At regular intervals, a portion of the plot is haphazardly removed through disturbance (at 3 different levels).

The response variable is created by using repeated cover measures on each plot to draw a linear regression through the points, to eliminate temporal auto-correlation and generate an independent set of response variables.  The slope of this regression is the response variable, which is **change in percentage of plot covered by the species per annum.**

I have generally been suffering from low power.  I am interested in testing the interaction of site and treatment, but am interested in using a 1 tailed test, testing if **Site A is more heavily affected by treatments than site B**  (in other words, if sites with lower initial species cover are more affected by disturbance treatments).  I can't think of a biological reason to test the other way around (that higher initial species cover would yield higher vulnerability to disturbance).

Another reason I want to use a 1 tailed test is because when I looked at the slopes of the treatments at each site, it became apparent that Site A was losing cover while Site B was remaining fairly stable.

My questions are:
1) Is it appropriate to use a one-tailed distribution to increase power in this situation?
2) Is it tautological (or logically unsound) to look at the means of each site and decide a 1-tailed test is appropriate?
3) At this point (not having yet used a 1-tailed F table but wanting to), is this decision still considered a priori?  Or am i now in the post-hoc zone since the data have already been collected?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My rule of thumb for a one tailed test is to ask "If the result was in the opposite direction to that which I expect (or hypothesize) will my conclusions be the same as if there is no difference?" If that isn't true, then you shouldn't be doing a one tailed test. For example, if you are seeing if some doctors have more patients die than would be expected, because you suspect the doctors are murdering their pateints, a one tailed test should be used. If a doctor has exactly the expected number of patients die, or fewer than the expected number of patients die, your conclusions are the same - there is no evidence they're murdering the patients.

The only time I've seen one tailed used is if the p-value is marginally significant. No one ever says they're using a one-tailed test if their p-value is 0.001 or 0.800, because there's no need. So the use of one-tailed tests immediately makes me believe that someone is trying to deceive me.

Yes, it's very unsound to look at the data and decide that a one-tailed test is appropriate. You could just make up a p-value if you want to, and this would also be unsound. What you're suggesting isn't that bad, but it's getting closer.

Finally, there's no such thing as a one-tailed F-table.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid, helpful and honest response.  I misspoke on the F-table, I was referring to the 0.95 quantile table as opposed to the 0.975 table.